# How to add checkboxes through code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to implement a form of picture selection and I want a checkbox to appear beside every picture that is added by the code, and I want each checkbox in the loop to have a different ID. I am trying to insert the checkboxes in the second `for` loop (which iterates over every picture in the data table).

This is my code:

```
string d = (string)Session["gouser"];
DataTable l = DAL.SelectFromTable(" Select * FROM [ClothesCatig] WHERE [UserID]='" + d + "'");

for (int i = 0; i < l.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataTable m = DAL.SelectFromTable(" Select * FROM [Closet] WHERE [UserID]='" + d + "' and [catig]='" + l.Rows[i][2].ToString() + "'");
    if (m.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("<center><div class='container12'>");
        Response.Write("<h4 class='ch'style='background-color: #985216;'>" + l.Rows[i][2] + "</h4>");
        Response.Write("<table class='table1'><tr>");
        for (int j = 0; j < m.Rows.Count; j++)
        {      
            Response.Write("<td><center><img src='images/hanger.png'/ width='80px'/>&nbsp;</br><img src='Cloth/"
                    + m.Rows[j][5].ToString() + "' width='80px'/></center></td>");
        }
        Response.Write("</table></tr>");
        Response.Write("</div></center>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using a gridview? Or why are you not using asp.net controls?

Comment: 2 Things. 1) Your code is potential exposed to [SQL Injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and 2) we stopped writing html out manually like this in about 1999.

Comment: This is how we learn in school I basically don't know any other way so if you know how to do it in this way please tell me